# Python- list of lists with values.tolist()

Tags: python, pandas

I need to read a single column from db table as a list of values. I tried to do that with following line of code:

```
ids_list = (pd.read_sql_query(q, db_internal.connection)).values.tolist()
```

when I use the `values.tolist()` it does what documentation says, that is turns the df into list of lists:

```
[['0x0043Fcb34e7470130fDe28198571DeE092c70Bd7'],
 ['0x00f93fBf00F97170B6cf295DC58888073CB5c2b8'],
 ['0x01FE650EF2f8e2982295489AE6aDc1413bF6011F'],
 ['0x0212133321479B183637e52942564162bCc37C1D']]
```

Because I am reading single column, I would like to transform it into list of values, not list of lists:

```
 ['0x0043Fcb34e7470130fDe28198571DeE092c70Bd7',
 '0x00f93fBf00F97170B6cf295DC58888073CB5c2b8',
 '0x01FE650EF2f8e2982295489AE6aDc1413bF6011F',
 '0x0212133321479B183637e52942564162bCc37C1D']
```

What would be a way to do that? I keep on finding solutions that are focused on list of lists

Comment: Add pandas as tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert tolist() generated list into list with the first element only.

```py
ids_list = list(i[0] for i in (pd.read_sql_query(q, db_internal.connection)).values.tolist())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate through the list with:

```
[i for i in ids_list[0]]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Why not do this in first place like this: `ids_list = list(i[0] for i in (pd.read_sql_query(q, db_internal.connection)).values.tolist()`

Comment: Thank you @PrabhasKumar, the solution works, only the last bracket was missing:ids_list = list(i[0] for i in (pd.read_sql_query(q, db_internal.connection)).values.tolist())

Comment: @Agnes fixed the bracket. Nice catch.